# boost::serialization of boost::optional of type with private default constructor

Tags: c++, boost-serialization, boost-optional

I'm upgrading from boost 1.54 to the latest 1.80 and have a compilation problem with boost serialization.

I have a class `A` with private default constructor. Another class `B` has a `boost::optional<A>` field and also is boost::serializable.
To allow boost::serialization to create an empty instance of `A` during boost::serialization, I had `friend class boost::serialization::access` within `A`. It worked with boost 1.54, because that version of boost used `access::construct<T>()` to create an instance and so it respected my friendship declaration. In 1.80 in contrast the instance of `optional<T>` is initialized simply as `t = T()`, which obviously does not work if T has private default constructor.

Is it simply a regression by oversight, or is there some deep thought behind the breaking change? And more importantly what is the recommended way of serializing `boost::optional<T>`, where `T` has a private default constructor?

Comment: “people that write classes without default constructors get what they deserve” — Alex Stepanov. Value classes should always have default constructors even if they create objects in a partially formed state. And only value classes deserve to be serialized in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found any better solution than to add the following friendship declaration to my class `A`, in addition to the existing `friend class boost::serialization::access` declaration:

```
template<class Archive, class T>
friend void boost::serialization::load(
   Archive & ar, boost::optional<T> & t, const unsigned int version);
```